# F# DataContractJsonSerializer StackOverflowException

Tags: f#, datacontractserializer, stack-overflow, netdatacontractserializer

```
dataElementsList : TypesAndData.DataElement list
```

is a list of 50,000 records (actually many more but let's start small).  I am trying to serialize to a JSON file:

```
let ser = Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<TypesAndData.DataElement list>) 
use ofs = File.OpenWrite(fileName)
let result = ser.WriteObject(ofs, dataElementsList)
```

and am getting the infamous StackOverflowException.  to be precise:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in FSharp.Core.dll

any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not try to serialize an F# list this way.  Convert it to an array with `List.toArray`.

(I expect that the DataContract serializers see lists as nested 'first'/'rest' data structures, which means 50000 tree depth of Json/Xml, which is not what you want.)

Comment: Did the trick I for giggles I paried down the list to 10 elements and it looked as though it was persisting the "inner structure" of the list - which makes sense if I think about it; thank you